# C# WebAPI2 on AppHarbor failed to serialize the response body for content

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, appharbor

I made a Simple C# WebAPI2 With EF6(codefirst) and when a try to get the data from the first class implemented "Categoria" im getting the error below:

The get: http://teste1-11.apphb.com/api/Categoria 
The error returning:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Migrations is enabled for context 'EventoContext' but the database does not exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations to create the database and its tables, for example by running the 'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.MigrationsChecker.IsMigrationsConfigured(InternalContext internalContext, Func`1 databaseExists)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClasse`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__d()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__14.MoveNext()"}}
```

to easy comprehension of the code, I'm giving below the complete cource code:

GITHUB REPO: https://github.com/frotaadriano/teste1

I tried some solutions (including some that I saw here , but without success).

Some pictures of the project ( all project is available on github)

[image: Configuration.cs]

[image: Categoria controller]

[image]

Comment: In this case EF is not finding the database that is quite strange because webapi projects creates and migrates database automatically. If this is your first project I suggest to use all the Visual Studio features than modify controllers according with your requirements. If you have 20 minutes you can have a look here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVc__TkiH7Y . Using SQL Server is very similar (you need only to change the connection on Web.config).

Comment: When I run Local the project works. I download another webApi project in Codeproject and this one runs local too and when a I publish it I see the same error. The project works local, maybe there is some configuration in appharbor to works